# How to get cognito id in a lambda function?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito, aws-lambda

How can I get the the cognito id of the user initiating the action in a Lambda function ?

the lambda function is triggered on s3 upload by a cognito authenticated user.

if I look in : event.Records[0].userIdentity.principalId, all i get is a string saying "CognitoIdentityCredentials"

Comment: Format and content of the data passed to the lambda function is controlled by S3, it might require some changes to enable Cognito identity id to appear in the event. Have you tried using Cognito sync to store your data ? Events triggered by Cognito updates already has identity id.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Vinay stated, we can't get the cognito id directly. Here is a workaround I implemented, if anyone is interested. It guarantees the authentication of your cognito user, but requires that you store files in a different directory per user:

- get the user to upload there file to 'yourBucket/cognito-id/*'
- set the cognito authenticated user's policy so they can't upload anywhere else  :

> "Resource":
>   "arn:aws:s3:::yourBucket/${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}/"

- In your lambda function, read the cognito id from the file key, for example :

> id = event.Records[0].s3.object.key.split('/')[0]

Comment: Great solution! More detail on the concepts behind how this works (IAM Access Policies) is in the Amazon Cognito Developers Guide: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/devguide/identity/concepts/iam-roles/#access-policies

Answer (score 1):

Currently Cognito Identity Id is not available in the events triggered by S3. We will consider this feature in our backlog to add this field in all the events triggered by difference services which were authenticated using Cognito credentials.

Comment: It is also worth noting that it depends on how the Lambda function was triggered. If the function is triggered via the AWS Mobile SDK or Amazon API gateway, and the caller was authenticated with Cognito, then context.identity should be populated with information about the Cognito identity (more at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/programming-model.html#programming-model-context-object-properties). However, if it is triggered by another service such as S3, at least at this time, this property is not populated.